# authenticating user and display page

Tags: php

I have created my page and am trying to authenticate the user before granting the user access to the page. My problem is that i am using the method like so:

```
if($_SESSION['username']){
echo 'PAGE CONTENT HERE';

}else{
 SEND BACK TO LOGIN PAGE
}
```

Which works fine for some of my pages, but on my main page a populate select boxes with php from my db and when i use the metod above all of my options are displaying outside of the select (works fine if i dont echo the page out)

am i missing a trick here?

Comment: please share some more code, its difficult to understand from above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: page-to-redirect.php");
}

//Rest of the code....
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the echo, try using alternate syntax for php if/else: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

I use this and it doesn't get in the way of any of my page content or scripts.

```
<?php if(conditional): ?>
<p>plain html and what not here</p>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="#">more html here</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or a redirect using header("Location: redirect.php"); based on the session check code.

Comment: cheers guys, codebauss this is exactly what im looking for. the redirect you mention is already in use on my application, but surely the user just needs to know the  name of the page and go direct?

Comment: Even if they go to the name of the page directly, your if conditional is making sure they have a valid session. So what you will want to do is implement an expiration on that or you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to make sure the request comes from only your login page or have your login page populate another variable, whether $_SERVER or one you create as a sanity check if you want to be that precise. Hopefully this helps you along.